# C++ CLI Syntax: Generic method?

Tags: c++-cli

Anyone  can help`

I need to have a generic method which in C++/CLI.

I try the following at the moment:

```
generic<K, ref class U> 
void OnUpdate (
    K key,
    U update
);
```

Sadly it does not work. The method must accept K and U, and the C# definitions are:

```
void DataUpdate<K, U>(DataUpdate<K, U> update) where U : class;
```

(yes, the method is different - OnUpdate will check whether apoint to an interface has set, then call this method in the interface, like an event handler, so the parameters must match).

The generic syntax in C++/CLI eludes me. I have no problem defining K also to be a class.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is not that clear exactly what you are looking for.  Constraints must be declared with the *where* keyword:

```
generic<typename K, typename U> 
where U : ref class
void OnUpdate (K key, U update)
{
   // etc..
}
```